# python sqlite3 pickle type column has default value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

we know that in database system (in my case we use sqlite3 as example), we can use BLOB type (binary) or TEXT type to store any pickleable object.

```
data = [1,2,3] # b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.'
create table test (value BLOB)
cursor.execute("insert into test values (?)", (pickle.dumps(data),)
## this works
```

But what if we want to set a default value for the column?
for example

```
create table test (value BLOB default b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.')
## obviously this is not working.
```

I knew a solution is using base64

```
## because we know base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps([1,2,3])) =
## 'gANjYnVpbHRpbnMKc2V0CnEAXXEBKEsBSwJLA2WFcQJScQMu'
## so we can use:
create table test (value BLOB default 'gANjYnVpbHRpbnMKc2V0CnEAXXEBKEsBSwJLA2WFcQJScQMu')
```

BUT as far as I known, in SqlAlchemy PickleType, they didn't use base64 encoding. Because this need extra time.

Any one know if we want to set a default value for a pickletype column, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite uses 'x' or 'X' to preface BLOB string literals (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#hexint) so while this 
b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.' doesn't work.  This should:

```
create table test (value BLOB default X'80035d7100284b014b024b03652e')
```

Comment: your answer is awesome